# calling Json output from the remote site

Tags: php

I  want to show [this](http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?identifier=123&format=json) json url output  in table over [here](http://acreo.zxq.net/proj/index.php?page=home) which is producing error.

The line which the error is point is this

```
if ( isset($_GET['page'])=='home' && 
     $_GET['page']=='home' )
         include("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?identifier=123&format=json");
```

The error produced is:

> Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /www/zxq.net/a/c/r/acreo/htdocs/proj/index.php on line 65

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to set `allow_url_fopen = On` in your php.ini file.

Or at runtime, you can do

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "on");
```

By default, PHP disables the ability to call remote files via URL with `fopen()`, `file_get_contents()`, and the like.

If you don't have access to `ini_set()` but have `.htaccess` you can also try setting it in there.  See http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess.

```
# .htaccess
php_value allow_url_fopen 1
```

Comment: i have to just call in the page

Comment: @user667340 You mean you need to use `ini_set()` at runtime?  Should work just fine then.

Comment: Actually  i am not cleared about runtime. i  have set in php page but its not working . i have simply added like this ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "on");
if(isset($_GET['page'])=='home' && $_GET['page']=='home' ) include("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?identifier=123&format=json");

Comment: @user667340 Does it work if you use `file_get_contents()` instead of `include()`?  Like this: `$json_string = file_get_contents("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com...");`

Comment: for localhost its same error but now for the server  its Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /www/zxq.net/a/c/r/acreo/htdocs/proj/index.php on line 62 . Is there any solution for it

Comment: @user667340 See my edit about setting the option in `.htaccess`

Comment: now its giving Warning: Warning: file_get_contents(http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?identifier=123&format=json) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /www/zxq.net/a/c/r/acreo/htdocs/proj/index.php on line 64

Comment: Perhaps they have it blocked for access by PHP user-agents?  Verify that you can `file_get_contents()` on something like `http://www.google.com`

Comment: I also get a 403 when I try it.  They might have rules forbidding access to their json API by php.

Comment: I was able to get the json from the command line using cURL, but not with PHP using fopen or file_get_contents (403 errors).  You might try to use cURL instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: The api which i want to access is created by me , and i have not set any permission ,i have put the same code on the other server its not producing error but its not displaying anything i have written like this echo $json_string = file_get_contents("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/api.php?  identifier=123&format=json")  should i need to print in other ways

Comment: @user667340 If it's not displaying anything and no error (if the server is setup to display errors) then it has probably retrieved the json correctly.  Just `echo $json_string;` to see it.

Comment: @user667340 If it continues not to work on the production server, I would contact the hosting provider, as they may have some block in place to prevent outbound http requests and return a 403 instead.

Comment: As i have echo it . Might be its hosting problem . Thanks alot . i have learned alot from you . Now i will give a try to cURL

Comment: Best of luck. This is a perplexing problem.